# (polar coordinates)

Tags: definite-integrals, polar-coordinates, change-of-variable

a $$\int_{0}^{\frac {4}{3}}\int_{0}^{\sqrt{4x-x^{2}}}\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}\;dx\;dy$$
 b $$\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{\sqrt{4x-x^2}}\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}\;dx\;dy$$

for (b)
$x=1$ so, $y=\sqrt{4x-x^2}= \sqrt{4*1-1}= \sqrt3$

$r^2=x^2+y^2$

$r^2= (1)^1+(\sqrt3)^2$

$r^2=\sqrt4$ so $r=2$

now $\theta=\arctan (y/x)=\arctan(\sqrt3)=\pi/3$

so the double integral will be:
$4\pi/3$ for ($0<\theta<\pi/3$  , and $0<r<2$ )

[I do not know if my answer correct or not and I'm not sure how I can solve (a) anyone can help me!]

Comment: I see formulas but I have no idea what your Question is about.  Please review [ask].  The body of a Question should make a fairly self-contained presentation of the problem you want help with (and multiple unrelated problems in one post are discouraged).